# Variance of MLE $\sigma^2$ estimator

Tags: variance

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be an i.i.d. random sample from $N(\mu,σ^2)$.

a. I found the estimator MLE of $\sigma^2$
$$\hat{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2$$
But how to calculate:
$$Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2)$$
Please help me.
I try write that $$\hat{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \overline{X}^2$$ and
how compute it $$Var(\hat{\sigma^2})$$

Comment: Well you know that $(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2)/\sigma^2$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution, right?

Comment: Yes i know that

Comment: You can solve this problem using the variance formula for a $\chi^2$ random variable.

Comment: I totally don't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: I try to solve this problem by Fisher Information $$I(\sigma^2)=-E(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial^2 \sigma^2} ln(f(x,\mu,\sigma^2)))=-E(-\frac{(x-\mu^2)}{2\sigma^6}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^4})$$ is it right?

Comment: ok I get that this variance equal  $$ \frac{2 \sigma^4}{n}$$ but i still don't know how to compute this without fisher information, analytical method

Answer (score 1):

Since ${\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2\over\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{(n-1)},$ we get 
$V(\hat\sigma^2) = {\sigma^4\over n^2}\,V\left(\chi^2_{(n-1)}\right)=\displaystyle {2\sigma^4(n-1)\over n^2}.$

Comment: Why my variance $$\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}$$ is other than yours?

Comment: @altodeaitana You must have an error in your calculations.

Comment: i'm sure my answer and calculations